# Create React apps using Kotlin and External

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-js

I'm trying to wrap this simple API: https://github.com/github-tools/github, just for study purpose. So, I created this external classes:

```
package index

import com.github.jesty.githubapi.Result
import com.github.jesty.githubapi.User
import kotlin.js.Promise

external class GitHub(user: User) {
    fun getUser(): GHUser
}

external class GHUser {
    fun listStarredRepos(): Promise<Result>
}
```

In a simple KotlinJS project everything is ok, but when I try to use in a project created with [Create React Kotlin App](https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app) I have the error below:

```
ReferenceError: GitHub is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved, I need to annotate the external class with @JsModule("github-api"):

```
package com.github.jesty.githubapi

import kotlin.js.Promise

@JsModule("github-api")
external class GitHub(user: User) {
    fun getUser(): GHUser
}

@JsModule("github-api")
external class GHUser {
    fun listStarredRepos(): Promise<Result>
}
```